# PFObject.pinAllIBackground use much memory

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I need download from MyClass 100 000 rows, I use this func, but I don't understand
PFObject.pinAllIBackground use much memory.

```
func downloadData(code:String, skip: Int, limit: Int ){
    let download = PFQuery(className: «MyClass»)
    download.limit = limit
    download.skip = skip
    download.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(){ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, block: {(success:Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    if objects!.count == limit {
                        let newskip = skip + limit
                        print("Page - \(newskip)")
                        self.downloadData(code, skip: newskip, limit: limit)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[Memory Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Upy5.png)